# UIGestureRecognizer: difficult to tap moving objects

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an xcode iOS project I'm working on where I have falling particles coming from the top of the screen down to the bottom. Based on the accelerometer, they can either fall fast, or slow.

They are all UIImageViews that are falling, and when I tap them, they should just stop moving. This works fine if they are moving slow enough and I seem to tap just a little bit under them. The problem with this is that when I tap right on top of them when they are moving fast, I can never seem to hit them.

What's the solution to this? Do I need to make a bigger UIImageView with a smaller UIImage centered in it? Or can I use the UIGestureRecognizer to look for taps in a larger radius?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UITapGestureRecognizer

(or)

Try to catch the touch event using `touchesBegan:` method.

Try writing the `touchesBegan:` method as follows:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
     if (touch.view == UIImageView)
     {
           // execute the code you need to stop the UIImageView from moving
     }
}
```

Hope this helps. All the best with your app :-)